# Accessing global variable across multiple objects in Java

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I got a very basic question (new to Java) and which goes as below. To give a bit of background, I am using BDD driven test automation framework, working with CUCUMBER and JAVA.

I want to set a global variable in my main class object depending on the parameter/value in one of my step definitions and then access the same variable across the test in other step definitions (or objects)

Let's say my class is

```
public class FeatureStepDefinitions{

@Given("I want to login to system as (.+)$")
public void iWantToLoginToSystemAs(String userType)
{
  //some logic
 }
@When("I send a request for user type (.+)$")
public void iSendRequestForUserType(String userType)
{
 //some logic
}
@Then("I should be able to see the right response$")
public void iShouldBeAbleToSeeTheRightResponse()
{
  if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz")
 {
  //verify this logic
 }

 else if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")
 {
  //verify that logic
  }
}
```

I know I can use the parameter **"userType"** in my THEN statement and perform this, but my question is if I do not want to refactor an existing then and still want to verify different behaviours depending on *userType* set in previous steps. 
Any help/direction is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to share state between steps in cucumber-jvm is to use Dependency Injection. 
From the [Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/#dependency-injection):

"If your programming language is Java, you will be writing glue code (step definitions and hooks) in plain old Java classes.

Cucumber will create a new instance of each of your glue code classes before each scenario.

If all of your glue code classes have an empty constructor, you don’t need anything else. However, most projects will benefit from a dependency injection (DI) module to organize your code better and to share state between step definitions.

The available dependency injection modules are:

PicoContainer (The recommended one if your application doesn’t use another DI module)
Spring
Guice
OpenEJB
Weld
Needle"

While you **can** declare a variable in your step definitions class to share state between the step definitions, this will only allow you to share between step definitions declared in **the same file**, and not between files. 
As the number of step definition grows, you'll want to group them in some meaningful way, and this approach will no longer suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of digging around and found its quite simple.

```
public class FeatureStepDefinitions{

public Static String globalUserType = null;

@Given("I want to login to system as (.+)$")
public void iWantToLoginToSystemAs(String userType)
{
  globalUserType = userType;
  //some logic
}
@When("I send a request for user type (.+)$")
 public void iSendRequestForUserType(String userType)
{
  //some logic
 }
@Then("I should be able to see the right response$")
 public void iShouldBeAbleToSeeTheRightResponse()
 {
  if(globalUserType.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz")
   {
     //verify this logic
   }

   else if(globalUserType.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")
   {
    //verify that logic
    }
  }
```